# Are "using typename" directives not implemented by compilers?

Tags: c++, using, nested-class, typename

I have some code which looks like this:

```
namespace myLibrary
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        struct Nested
        {
            ...
        };

        ...
    };
}
```

In some other parts of the code, I need to access A. Since I like readable code, I also like the using directive:

```
using myLibrary::A;
...
A a;
```

Now, at some point I also need to access my nested class, so I want to write something like this:

```
using myLibrary::A::Nested;
```

Obviously, the compiler can't know that this is a nested class and not a class member, and gives me an error:

```
error : using declaration can not refer to class member
```

What I can't understand is why this does not solve the problem:

```
using typename myLibrary::A::Nested;
```

The compiler still gives me the exact same error!

Luckily, I have alternatives:

```
// Using a typedef
typedef myLibrary::A::Nested Nested;

// Using the new C++11 syntax for type aliasing
using Nested = myLibrary::A::Nested;
```

but I'd like to understand why the *using typename* directive did not work. Does it not do what I think it does? Or is it not implemented by compilers? If it is the latter, is there a reason for it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's only intended for namespace members, not class members:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using

Comment: @DiscoStu: maybe, but in this case why introduce the "typename" keyword? It seems to be supposed to work with using: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: What is the context in which you're trying to use the using-declaration?

Comment: @dyp: no special context, I use them like I'd use a typedef. Namely, on top of a .cpp file, juste after the #include directives

Comment: Hmm.. These kind of using-directives can be used inside classes to refer to members of base classes (make them visible). Not sure why they're illegal outside of classes, even when they refer to types.

Comment: `Nested` must always be referred to as `A::Nested` unless it's in member variables or functions of `A`.  If your code seems to call for talking about `Nested` without `A::` , that's a sign that it might be a better design not to have it as a nested class.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well so what about the `typedef`? That's almost the same as a using-declaration, just more boilerplate. IMO, it leads to the question *why isn't it allowed to use a using-declaration naming a nested type outside a derived class*?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: if you want to know, A is a class describing a robotic joint and Nested is a struct of the angular limitations of the joint. It makes sense to me to have it nested, even though I sometime have to access it from the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `using` declaration referring to a namespace member `A` may only appear at namespace or local scope.

A `using` declaration referring to a class member `Nested` may only appear at class scope (along with member declarations), in a class derived from `Nested`. In fact, such `using` declarations are grammatically considered to be member declarations. They are used to adjust access qualification, and (with `typename`) to allow members of type-dependent bases to be used without qualification. These are specific use cases, so member `using` declarations are a bit specialized.

A nested class *is* a member of its enclosing class. You should generally avoid using class enclosures as a substitute for namespaces. Metaprogramming provides some exceptions to the rule, but in those cases you still wouldn't use `using` declarations, at least at namespace scope, because namespaces cannot be templated. Inheriting from an empty metaprogramming class is viable, but do mind the spaghetti.

The `using` directive is a different beast. It looks like `using namespace` and it links one namespace to another as a fallback path in name lookup.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "using typename directive". There are *using-directives* and *using-declarations*.

You're not using any *using-directives*, and they aren't relevant to the question in any case (they name namespaces, and can't use the typename keyword).

When *using-declarations* happen to appear within class templates, and happen to name dependent types, they have to use the `typename` keyword just like anything else that happens to be in a template and happens to name a dependent type.

For example:

```
template <typename A, typename R>
class Functor : public std::unary_function<A, R>
{
    using typename std::unary_function<A, R>::result_type;
    using typename std::unary_function<A, R>::argument_type;
 public:
    result_type operator() (argument_type) {}
};
```

In your situations, the namespace-declaration does not appear to be a part of the body of a class template, in fact it appears to be at namespace scope, in which case attempting to name a class member (doesn't matter if it's a type or a function or whatever) violates `7.3.3[namespace.udecl]/8`

> A *using-declaration* for a class member shall be a *member-declaration*

as the compiler correctly diagnosed with "error : using declaration can not refer to class member"

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for calling it a "directive". I thought that the difference was that the "using declarations" were those in the body of a class and the "using directives" the others.